# CSS: Show column of images as narrow as possible without using table

Tags: html, css

I have a web page showing text and, at the right-hand side, a list of logos.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="contentArea">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
       Cras quis justo porta elit sollicitudin consequat ut in massa.
       etc. etc.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="logoArea">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x100">
    <br/>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x100">
    <br/>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100">
</div>
```

To get the contentArea at the left and the logoArea at the right, I have the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .contentArea {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .logoArea {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 1%;
    }
</style>
```

This works fine. **The logo area is a wide as the widest logo**, which is important. However, using display `table-cell` looks weird and misused. What is the recommended way to do this in CSS? I have to support browsers since 2012, e.g. Android 4.1.2 has to be supported.

The website I'm talking about is [www.admiraalit.nl](http://www.admiraalit.nl).

Comment: the use of display with any value is not weird but can be misused when not needed. display:table is defaut display of table, list-item is defaut for li and block for p and div , ... do not misunderstand the use of  HTML and CSS. HTML can be styled via CSS but a div will always be a div even with display:none; ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus, is it valid CSS to use display value `table-cell`, but not use `table` / `table-row`? Or is it just a coincidence that this works in all browsers I've tested?

Comment: for display:table, it is from IE8 and any other browsers (firefox 1 did for instance) it was in the draft since 1998 and because of IE6 for ages nobody used it untill FF1 around 2004 ;) flex is very new and not implemented as well as table. i really do not get your trouble here. My android 2.3 has no trouble with it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to the CSS [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

For browser support, check the following [`link`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Here is a quick example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">
    this is the content area
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work in older browsers like Android 4.1.2, not even with `-webkit-` prefix.
I have updated my question to be more specific about browser support.

Comment: Ah, I've got it working on Android 4.1.2!  I had to use `display: -webkit-box;` and `-webkit-box-flex: 1;`

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but shouldn't `flex : 1` have the prefixes as well?

Comment: Thanks, accepted. It's a pity that it takes 7 extra lines of css and 2 extra lines of HTML (for the wrapper) compared to my original solution with `table-cell`.

Comment: you should use a prefixer to bother less with this extra line of code. your style sheet will be cleaner. prefix do become obsolete at one point ;)